# Area of a circle: semicircle proof - bounds of integration

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, circles, area

I was looking for a calculus proof of the area of a circle, and found the following on Wikipedia:

$$\small\begin{aligned}
A_{\text{semicircle} }(r)&=\int_{\color{green}{-r} }^{\color{green}{r} }\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\, dx \\\\
&=\int_{\color{orange}{-\pi/2} }^{\color{orange}{\pi/2} }\sqrt{r^2(1-\sin\theta)}r\cos\theta\, d\theta \\\\
&=2r^2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^2\theta\, d\theta \\\\
&=\frac{\pi r^2}2 \\\\\\
A_{\text{circle} }(r)&=2\cdot\frac{\pi r^2}2 \\\\
&=\pi r^2
\end{aligned}$$

I know how to get the second integral from the first using trig substitution, but I got different bounds of integration, i got the following:

$$\small\int_{\color{blue}{-x/\sin\theta} }^{\color{blue}{x/\sin\theta} }\sqrt{r^2(1-\sin\theta)}r\cos\theta\,d\theta$$

**My question is**: how do I get the bounds in orange ($-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if the substitution is x = rsin(t) then consider for which t rsint=r or rsint=-r

Comment: Makes sense. If $x=-r$, $r\sin\theta=-r$, so $\theta=-\pi/2$, and the same can be done for $x=r$. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that, in order to compute$$\int_{-r}^r\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\,\mathrm dx,$$you do the substitution $x=r\sin(\theta)$ and $\mathrm dx=r\cos(\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta$. In order to still have $x\in(-r,r)$, you take $\theta\in\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right)$.

Comment: I see, I was viewing the problem only from an algebraic perspective. Now that I got the reasoning, I can see how your answer makes sense. Thanks!